# Run a map natively in a cordova app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, mapbox-gl

is it possible to run a map (using mapbox) natively in iOS/Android and embed it in a cordova app? The map should have interactive elements, like markers and popups, which interact with the html/JS interface.

Must this be done via a custom plugin?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for that

http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/mapbox

They also provide a test app that demonstrates how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GoogleMaps plugin to show markers and popups etc. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: thanks. I forgot to mention that we will use map box, since we have a custom map design.